# Send Response as 200 manually using actions in reactjs to UI

Tags: reactjs, axios, action

I am sending the status in actions like this but not able to fetch the status as 200 in UI, here I need to send the response manually,but in UI I am getting whole function can anyone please help me to send only response as 200

This is the actions page:

```
export const updateTasks = (Id, decision) => async (dispatch) => {
console.log("Inside actions");
let res = {
status: 200,
};
console.log(res.status);
return res.status;
};
```

in UI i am calling like this

```
 const ResponseStatus = updateTasks(
 Id,decisionObj
 );
 console.log(ResponseStatus);
```

Please help me to send only response as 200 to UI